# Ubuntu 13.10 not booting, startpar bridge

Tags: boot

I cannot identify the reason for this, as I didn't change anything special.

On booting, Ubuntu is stuck in the loading screen. With F1 I get

```
starting startpar bridge for notification of upstart job start/stop 
stopping startpar bridge for notification of upstart job start/stop
```

multiple times.

When I switch to command line I can log in, but I have no idea how to fix this issue there. Network is not working then either, although the computer is connected via cable. Maybe the network config is not loaded (DHCP is off). So I cannot run updates or reinstall.

I tried all options in recovery mode. Enable networking is not working.

I can think of something like this:
1. enable networking
2. reinstall boot loader stuff (GRUB, upload, ...)

Comment: This bug report may be related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sysvinit/+bug/1324627

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. A google search indicates that many people seem to have this problem, and I don't see solutions. Startpar starts runlevel scripts in parallel, so is there to speed up the booting process. It is part of the [sysvinit](http://savannah.nongnu.org/svn/?group=sysvinit) package, which is marked as essential. This means it is hard to remove or substitute, which was one of my first ideas.

I spent several hours extensively searching and trying to remove this problem in order to have my system boot again. I even downloaded and compiled the [sysvinit repository](http://savannah.nongnu.org/svn/?group=sysvinit), compiled it and replace my existing binary in /sbin/ with the built one (v0.58->v0.59), but I noticed that this svn repository was not very new. All this to no avail.

I ended up downgrading my system again by doing a reinstall from live-CD. (BTW, Precise is supported until 2017.)

(I don't have 10 reputation points to post more than two links, so I had to cut back.)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. In my case it was connected with package `bride-utils`, which I needed to install:

```
sudo apt-get install bride-utils
```

Comment: I needed to actually install bridge-utils by using a Live CD and creating a temporary chroot environment. The /etc/resolv.conf was kind of messed up for some reason (possibly the syntax I used to cp to chroot is to blame), and I couldn't add anything to the resolv.conf as it complained about not being able to overwrite the link. So I removed the link and add an resolv.conf file with my normal settings which allowed for me to install bridge-utils

Answer (score 0):

Wow, a lot of stuff broke when I upgraded to 13.10 (gee).

Anyway, I did some searching based on the same keywords, since I had the same symptoms as you, and found that this bug affected me:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1270436

> When I attempt to install and boot using lightdm, the system stops at startpar-bridge and will not advance into boot. I switched to kdm and system boots properly. This bug reared it's ugly head after installation of nvidia-331 from the Ubuntu repo's.
>
> This into 14.04 Kubuntu.

I switched to `gdm` as a workaround, and now I can log in. See if that does it for you.